# using System.Net.NetworkInformation, is there a way to bind a ping to a specific interface?

Tags: c#, networking

Although the Ping.Send() is easy and straightforward, I can't seem to figure out how to Ping.Send() out of the interface I choose. specifically my WLAN interface or my Ethernet interface when both are connected to separate networks.

Would I have to use the Sockets namespace and the Bind(localEndpoint)?

It seems odd that that binding functionality isn't available in the NetworkInformation.Ping utility. Or is it & I just can't find it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICMP is not socket based.  The ping will be sent to the appropriate port based on the routing table.

Comment: Ah, so if I understand you correctly, I can look at the routing table to see which interface it would go through and *route add* if necessary.

Thanks.