# Is it possible to ping from a source IP address to a destination IP address in C#?

Tags: c#, ping

I have been tasked with verifying the connectivity between various devices that I can't query directly. The way the C programmers did it in the past was to create a batch file with lines like:

ping -n 5 -S [Source Address] [Destination Address] >> OutputFile.txt

Then they run the batch file and open the output file and parse the results to find out if it worked.

In C# I know I can simply write:

Ping pinger = new Ping();
PingReply reply = pinger.Send(DestinationAddress);

and check reply.Status for IPStatus.Success

But this does not specify the source address. I have searched but I haven't been able to find a way to do anything like the command line shown above in C#. Is there no new and better way than this old kluge?

Comment: source address will be always you. Isn't it?

Comment: @rodelarode On multihomed systems you can have more than 1 IP so specifying source makes sense on those systems.

Comment: Did you check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/26635253/215042 ?

Comment: Yes it is possible but why do you need *source address*? Do you know how to get all those *source address*es your system has?

Comment: RobIII - Yes, that looks like exactly what I need. Thanks for the link!